# Arduino залипание

Tags: arduino

Всем привет.
Написал тут код, он в целом работает, но иногда зависает по какой-то причине. 
Вот сам код:

```
#include <EEPROMex.h>   //библиотека для работы со внутренней памятью ардуино
#include <avr/sleep.h>  //библиотека режимов сна

#define mosfet_pin 2  //реле или мосфет на D2
#define trigger_pin 3 //спусковая кнопка на D3
#define out_pin 4     //5v D4
#define out_pin2 5    //5v D5
#define fireled 6    //пин индикатора работы и блокировки

volatile unsigned long lastshot;  //время последнего нажатия для таймера сна

boolean trig_state; //переменная для хранения текущего состояняи кнопки
boolean flag;       //флажок для запоминания положения кнопки
boolean block;      //флажок для запоминания блокировки
boolean waitblink;  //флажок для ожидания 5 миганий
int presscount;     //считаем кол-во нажатий
byte trigger;       //положение спусковой кнопки

float my_vcc_const;  // константа вольтметра

int voltage;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  my_vcc_const = EEPROM.readFloat(8);
  block = 0;

  pinMode(mosfet_pin, OUTPUT); //сформировать пин реле как выход
  pinMode(trigger_pin, INPUT_PULLUP); //пин кнопки подтянут внутренним резистором, резистор на 10 кОм НЕ НУЖЕН
  pinMode(out_pin, OUTPUT); //5v
  pinMode(out_pin2, OUTPUT); //5v
  attachInterrupt(1, trigger_press, FALLING);  //аппаратное прерывание при нажатии на кнопку (проснуться)
}

void trigger_press() { //обработчик прерывания  
  //просыпаемся при нажатии кнопки!
}

void loop() {
  voltage = readVcc();
  //Serial.println(voltage);

  trig_state = digitalRead(trigger_pin); //считать положение кнопки fire

  if(trig_state == 1 && flag == 1) //если кнопка отжата и флаг=1
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(mosfet_pin, LOW);  //закрыть мосфет            
    flag=0;    //ставим флажок, что кнопка больше не нажата
    Serial.print("STOP FIRE!!!");
  }

  if(trig_state == 0 && flag == 0 && waitblink == 0) //если кнопка fire нажата флаг=0 и мод не мигает
  {  
     if(presscount > 3)
     {
        if(block == 0)
        { 
            waitblink = 1;

            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
                delay(200);
                digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
                delay(200);
            }
            waitblink = 0;
            block = 1;
            Serial.print("BOXMOD IS BLOCKED!!!");
        }
        else 
        {
            //delay(200);
            waitblink = 1;

            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            {
                digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
                delay(200);
                digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
                delay(200);
            }
            waitblink = 0;
            block = 0;
            Serial.print("BOXMOD UNLOCKED!!!");
        }
     }

     if(block == 0)
     {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(mosfet_pin, HIGH);  //открыть мосфет
        Serial.print("FIRE!!!");
        Serial.print("Press count: "); Serial.println(presscount, 3);
        Serial.print("Wait blink: "); Serial.println(waitblink, 3);
     }

     presscount ++;
     lastshot=millis();    //запомнить время последнего нажатия (для таймера сна)
     flag=1;         //поставить флажок, что кнопка нажата
  }

// этот кусок даёт команду спать
  if (millis()-lastshot > 300)     //если после последнего нажатич прошло больше 3 секунд
  {
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); // выбор режима энергопотребления
    sleep_mode();                        // уходим в спячку
    presscount = 0;
  }
// этот кусок даёт команду спать

delay(1);   //задержка для стабильности работы прошивки
}

void calibration() {
  //--------калибровка----------
  for (byte i = 0; i < 7; i++) EEPROM.writeInt(i, 0);          // чистим EEPROM для своих нужд
  my_vcc_const = 1.1;
  Serial.print("Real VCC is: "); Serial.println(readVcc());     // общаемся с пользователем
  Serial.println("Write your VCC (in millivolts)");
  while (Serial.available() == 0); int Vcc = Serial.parseInt(); // напряжение от пользователя
  float real_const = (float)1.1 * Vcc / readVcc();              // расчёт константы
  Serial.print("New voltage constant: "); Serial.println(real_const, 3);
  EEPROM.writeFloat(8, real_const);                             // запись в EEPROM
  while (1); // уйти в бесконечный цикл
  //------конец калибровки-------
}

long readVcc() { //функция чтения внутреннего опорного напряжения, универсальная (для всех ардуин)
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega32U4__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX4) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
#elif defined (__AVR_ATtiny24__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny44__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny84__)
  ADMUX = _BV(MUX5) | _BV(MUX0);
#elif defined (__AVR_ATtiny25__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny45__) || defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__)
  ADMUX = _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2);
#else
  ADMUX = _BV(REFS0) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2) | _BV(MUX1);
#endif
  delay(2); // Wait for Vref to settle
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC); // Start conversion
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA, ADSC)); // measuring
  uint8_t low  = ADCL; // must read ADCL first - it then locks ADCH
  uint8_t high = ADCH; // unlocks both
  long result = (high << 8) | low;

  result = my_vcc_const * 1023 * 1000 / result; // расчёт реального VCC
  return result; // возвращает VCC
}
```

Видео для наглядности: https://vk.com/video16479439_456239166